# Unable to build android apk file from ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to IONIC. My problem is that I am trying to build an apk file using downloaded project. I getting an error. Attaching my logs for reference. Any help would be great

Using this command to  build apk `ionic cordova build android --prod --release`

````
> ionic-v1.cmd build
[17:21:38] Invoking sass gulp task.
> cordova.cmd build android --release
Running command: node E:\Ionic Projets\zmNinja-master\hooks\before_prepare\02_jshint.js E:\Ionic Projets\zmNinja-master

cordova-custom-config: Skipping auto-restore of config file backup(s)
Running command: node E:\Ionic Projets\zmNinja-master\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js E:\Ionic Projets\zmNinja-master
Running command: node E:\Ionic Projets\zmNinja-master\hooks\after_prepare\020_remove_sass_from_platforms.js E:\Ionic Projets\zmNinja-master
Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "glob" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android --release exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.```
````